# Is there such a thing as meta tagging graphics on a web page?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I've been doing some web work for a client and they've asked me to meta tag images on their web page with some specific data,  I've not heard of meta tagging images, at least not using standard html before and a quick search reveals that there isn't a standard meta tag for this.  However I did notice facebook OpenGraph protocol but I'm pretty sure that's not what he wants.

Has my client been ill informed about something or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the images are JPEG then you can store meta data using [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format).

That said, you should probably find out what your client wants to achieve with the meta data and solve *that* problem.

Comment: It's that he's been advised that it improves search engine rankings

Comment: Sounds like he's talking about using proper alt and title attributes on the image tag. But also be aware of any client that claims to have SEO knowledge (they usually don't).

Comment: Someone is trying to sell him snake oil. Search engine rankings are still best improved by having good, accessible, unique content and sensible links to it. Meta data is all but worthless (you'll get the most use out of `description` … when you want a specific summary rather than an auto-generated one).

Comment: Possibly it was [Rich snippets](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=99170), [Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) and [schema.org](http://www.schema.org/docs/schemas.html) that form the basis of the snake oil.  You still have to have unique content and good links, but allows you to indicate what sort of content you have.